# Results based in "results of subquery filled"

Tags: mysql

I will try to explain as detailed as possible since is more like a strange need.

The target is to get a subquery of products that match a simple conditions (like brand = 1, manufacturer = 3 etc) but also the remaining products that don't "match all options of subquery" based on one column (quantity).

So the product has "id, category, brand, manufacturer, **delivery** and **quantity**".

I have a configuration for this "quantity" that doesn't have to get filled (so if it's not filled row is selected) and if matches previous results of brand or manufacturer should not get used to calculate this fill.

The tricky point is **package** and **delivery** and that "if not match previous conditions".

### Data:

I have a table that have a correlation of configurations of packages.
So:

- for package of 1 -> we can have only products of 1.
- for package of 2 -> we can have (2 products of 1) OR (1 product of 2)
- for package of 3 -> we can have (1 product of 1 AND 1 product of 2) OR (1 product of 3)

**

```
| idConfig | ConfigGroup | ProductQuantity | PackageQuantity |
| -------- | ----------- | --------------- | --------------- |
| 1        | 1           | 1               | 1               |
| 2        | 2           | 1               | 2               |
| 3        | 2           | 1               | 2               |
| 4        | 3           | 2               | 2               |
| 5        | 4           | 1               | 3               |
| 6        | 4           | 2               | 3               |
| 7        | 5           | 3               | 3               |
| 8        | 6           | 2               | 4               |
| 9        | 6           | 2               | 4               |
```

### The target

If I search for: Products with brand = 1, Manunfacturer = 2 and PackageQuantity = 3

I expect to get all products of brand 1, Manufacturer 2 and also, of the remaining products, products with same **delivery** that don't fill package.

I imagine that i need a subuquery to do this in "two Rounds"

```
| idProduct | ProductBrand | ProductManufacturer | ProductDelivery | ProductQuantity |
| --------- | ------------ | ------------------- | --------------- | --------------- |
| 1         | 1            | 1                   | 1               | 1               |
| 2         | 2            | 1                   | 2               | 2               |
| 3         | 2            | 2                   | 2               | 3               |
| 4         | 2            | 1                   | 2               | 2               |
| 5         | 2            | 1                   | 3               | 3               |
| 6         | 2            | 1                   | 3               | 1               |
| 7         | 2            | 1                   | 3               | 2               |
| 8         | 2            | 1                   | 4               | 1               |
| 9         | 2            | 2                   | 4               | 2               |
```

Should process like this:

Round one:

- Product 1 selected because brand = 1
- Product 3 selected because manufacturer = 2
- Product 9 selected because manufacturer = 2

Round two (remaining products):

- Product 2 selected because Quantity 2, and not porducts with quantity 1 available to fill configGroup 4
- Product 4 selected because Quantity 2, and not products with quantity 1 available to fill configGroup 4
- Product 8 selected because Quantity 1, and not products with quantity 2 available to fill configGroup 4

Results should select product ids: 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9

It is possible?

EDIT:
My closest aproach right now is:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pr.Id)
FROM products AS pr
LEFT JOIN manufacturer AS mn
LEFT JOIN Brand AS br

WHERE pr.Brand = 1
AND pr.Manufacturer = 2
AND pr.Id NOT IN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pr2.Id)
    FROM products AS pr2
    LEFT JOIN packages AS pk ON pk.ProductQuantity = pr2.Quantity
    
    WHERE pr2.Id NOT IN (
    SELECT pr3.Id
    FROM products AS pr3
    WHERE pr3.Brand = 1
    AND pr3.Manufacturer = 2)
    
    GROUP BY pk.configGroup, pr2.delivery
    
    HAVING SUM(pk.ProductQuantity) >= 3
    )
```

But this aproach didn't check if all options of ConfigGroup are used. Just the total amount.

For SUM(pk.ProductQuantity) > 3 in ConfigGroup 4 (1+2) only should select Id's if we have "products with qty 1" AND "products of qty 2". Right now if we have 4 products of qty 2 still gets selected.

Comment: Share the query that you have tried, the results you got, and the results you want.

I am afraid that your English/problem formulation is rather unintelligible, but code and clear tables might help to understand. Nobody understands `but also remaining that don't "fill a group" based on one column (quantity).`

Comment: Shared query example and improved text readability

Comment: I hope you solved this by now? Because your question is impossible for me to answer, not only the English, but also the examples, are confusing. I've spent ten minutes trying to figure out what your mean, and I get the general jist, but the query seems not to match the tables you show. Your first table (after the "**") for instance, which table name in the query is it? No clue.

Treat us like computers, with exact table names, column names, always the same,to get answers. Now everybody is giving up trying to understand what you mean.

Comment: If I could match your data to the table and column names in your query I could maybe understand what you want and help. I see table names and column names that are not in the data you are giving us.